# Blender is exporting the wrong UV coordinates

Tags: uv, export, coordinates

I was making an axe model in blender but when i loaded it into my game engine the texture wasnt right. I tried making a textured cube to find the problem. When editing the texture in blender the cube renders properly, but when I export it the uv coordinates become seemingly randomly jumbled. I have checked the uv coordinates manually by going into the file and checking them and something is definitely not right.
I'm including the texture and the obj file contents below:
[image: texture]

[Link to the obj file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7jyxu1ald31l8s/cube.obj?dl=0)

Comment: What happens when you try to re-import the model and apply the texture to the imported model? Is it still screwed up?

Comment: @Kirbinator I imported the .obj file into blender and then applied the texture to it. It worked fine. It looked like it should. I tried the exact files again in my game engine but still no change.

Comment: It comes out fine for me as well.  I have to assume it is something your game-engine is doing.

Comment: I have tested my engine many times while developing it and I have checked the obj file parser code twice. Like i said in the main part of the post, I went into the file and manually checked the uvs against the vertices on a piece of paper and the uvs are not exported properly

Comment: Maybe It's just your game engine that imports it wrong?

Comment: It wasnt. You're right. The obj file parser I was using couldn't handle texture seams. That's why it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just realised that I didn't post my solution to this problem. The problem was with my game engine code. My obj file parser couldn't handle texture seams and so it made the whole thing look dodgy.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

- Make super sure that you are indeed exporting the UV's when you export the obj.
  [image: Relevant Option]

  - Make sure that your game engine is consuming the UV information properly.

Comment: If I didn't export my uvs my engine would crash and give me an error. It requires uvs to be present,and they are. The engine also does take the UV information properly. I have tested it with other people's models and it works fine. Like i said, the UV information exported doesn't correctly map against the texture

Comment: When I export I use the settings:apply modifiers, write normals, include uvs, triangulate faces and objects as obj objects